# Uniformly distributed measures are unique up to multiplicative constant.

Tags: measure-theory, proof-explanation, geometric-measure-theory

I am reading the book Geometry of sets and measures in euclidean spaces of Mattila and Im having trouble understanding the last part of the proof of theorem 3.4

Definition: Let $X$ be a metric space and $\mu$ a Borel measure over $X$, if for all $0<r<\infty$ and $x,y \in X$ we have $$0 < \mu(B_r(x)) = \mu(B_r(y)) < \infty $$ we say that it is uniformly distributed

Then he proves

Theorem 3.4:
Let $\mu,\nu$ be uniformly distributed Borel regular measures on a separable metric space $X$, then there is a constant $c$ such that $\mu=c\nu$

He proves that for all open sets $U$ we have $\mu(U) = c\nu(U)$ and then says that by theorem 1.10 (2) and borel regularity of $\mu,\nu$ we have $\mu = c\mu$.

Theorem 1.10 (2) says: Let $\mu$ be a Borel regular measure on $X$, $A$ a $\mu$ measurable set and $\epsilon > 0$, If there are open sets $V_1,V_2,\dots$ such that $A \subset \bigcup_{i=1}^\infty V_i$ and $\mu(V_i) < \infty$ for all i, then there is an open set $V$ such that $A \subset V$ and $\mu(V\setminus A) < \epsilon$

And Borel regularity means that for all $A \subset X$ there is a Borel set $B$ such that $A \subset B$ and $\mu(A) = \mu(B)$

I understand the rest of proof except that part, could anyone please clarify it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The separability of $X$ implies that we can find a countable family of open balls $\{U_i\}_{i\geq 1}$ that cover $X$. Also, by the assumption on $\nu$, we have $\nu(U_i) < \infty$ for each $i$. This shows that Theorem 1.10(2) can be applied to any Borel-measurable subset of $X$.

Now let $A \in \mathcal{B}(X)$ be any Borel subset of $X$. Then for each choice $\varepsilon = \varepsilon_n = \frac{1}{n}$ (or with any choice of $(\varepsilon_n)_{n\geq 1}$ of positive numbers that vanish as $n\to\infty$), we can invoke Theorem 1.10(2) to find an open set $V_n$ such that

$$ A \subseteq V_n, \qquad\text{and}\qquad \nu(V_n \setminus A) < \varepsilon_n. $$

From this, we obtain

\begin{align*}
\mu(A)
\leq \mu(V_n)
= c\nu(V_n)
\leq c\nu(A) + c\varepsilon_n,
\end{align*}

and letting $n \to \infty$ shows that $\mu(A) \leq c \nu(A)$. Arguing similarly, with the role of $\mu$ and $\nu$ interchanged, we also obtain the inequality $c\nu(A) \leq \mu(A)$. Therefore we have the equality $\mu(A) = c\nu(A)$ for any Borel set $A$.

I am not sure why the author also mentioned Borel regularity, since I see no reason to deal with non-Borel-measurable sets in this argument.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, he mentions the Borel regularity because in his book, the definition he uses of measure is actually referring to an outer measure, so the results holds for all sets by borel regularity.